# Why am I failing to print my html file in beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

here is the sample code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml

with open('bdmain.html') as html_file:
     soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file, 'lxml')

print(soup)
```

The path seems to be correct, I'm not getting any error messages, it's just that nothing is printing at all for some reason

im scraping from this site: https://www.metrolyrics.com/bob-dylan-lyrics.html

Comment: Can you add your html file also

Comment: have you already got the HTML response and saved this into your html file? otherwise, you will be working with an empty bdmain.html file, so bs4 wouldnt have anything to parse?

Comment: is this all the code you are using? you are importing the Requests module but you are not creating a GET request to retrieve the contents of the website that you want to store as your html file

Comment: @VaibhavVishal That's incorrect. The `soup` variable is available after the `with` block too.

Comment: Do you have LXML parser installed on your system?

Comment: Hey sorry guys, i went to work on something else for a while, I wasn't expecting this many comments so quickly!

Comment: LXML is installed, and the html response was already grabbed and saved to a file, which as far as I can tell is in the correct directory to be grabbed within IDLE. I have edited the original post to include the html file im working with

Comment: lol never mind idk how to share a unique html file that is stored on my cpu. i dumb. but i did post the associated website im working with

Answer (score 2):

You could try this,

```
with open('bdmain.html') as html_file:
    contents = html_file.read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'lxml')

    print(soup)
```

This site might be helpful too: https://zetcode.com/python/beautifulsoup/

Comment: still no luck, it's not an issue with the code, must be an issue with the file or directory. ugh. noob problems